# Java and MySQL date problem

Tags: java, mysql, time

I do a 
rs.getTimestamp("datetime")

in Java.

In the database, this datetime is 2009/03/06 02:47:18

but the time is returned as 14:47:18

I'm not very knowledgeable about MySQL dates, so I would appreciate any explanation as to why this is happening.

Comment: Are you sure that the time in the DB is not 2:47:18 PM? Because that would be exactly 14:47:18

Comment: It is. 
Which just complicated using the time to retrieve records

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter. Its not about MySQL or any database. This is the format Timestamp shows up by default, I believe. It doesn't mean it missed the date or something.

You can always format the Timestamp returned by the method in any format in your code. Check out [java.text.SimpleDateFormat](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) class. Or for better, check out much more sophisticated [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: I format it using a SimpleDateFormatter, using HHmmss as my format.

Comment: Try small 'h'. Something like "hhmmss a"

Comment: For exact as MySQL, try "yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss"

Comment: I'll try that, but I might add that I do not get this problem if I use SQL Server

Comment: It worked, thanks, I'm not sure if it will work in the long run though.

Comment: as far as I can see, mySQL uses 12 hour time, and I don't know how to check whether it is am or pm. I need to use the time to find records, what if there are two times, looking exactly the same, but one am and one pm?

Comment: MySQL knows and has whatever it needs to know whether its AM or PM. May be you can configure your client to show that, or use some other client. Or I am afraid if you need to expand that column a bit to make that visible.

Answer (score 1):

Two things. First, I think we need sample code. What's going on is not at all clear from what you've given us. Context, usage, DB schema, and sample rows as well.

Second, [ResultSet.getTimestamp()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getTimestamp(java.lang.String)) should be returning an object of type [Timestamp](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html), rather than a String of any sort.

Answer (score 0):

SimpleDateFormat time      = new SimpleDateFormat("HHmmss");

datime = time.format(rs.getTimestamp("datetime"))

and then datime is printed to a file.

the datetime column in the table is a datetime Data Type

Comment: For exact as MySQL, try "yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss"